# Is there an equivalent to @BeforeAll in JMH(Java Microbenchmark Harness), Level.Trial is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, annotations, jmh

Hello and good morning from Germany!

Since my English isn’t very good, I can only offer you a ChatGPT translation of my question.

Here’s the issue: I’m using the JMH Tool to benchmark a SpringBoot application.
Before calling my @Benchmark methods, I have a @Setup method that is also annotated with @(Level.Trial). According to the JMH documentation, this means the following:

Trial level: To be executed before/after each run of the benchmark.
Despite my doubts about my English, I’ve had it translated, and I keep arriving at the conclusion that the following assertion should not fail:

```
   @Setup(Level.Trial)
   public void loginProcess()
   {
      setupCalls++; //This is a static field
      Assertions.assertEquals(1, setupCalls);
   }
```

```
   @Benchmark
   public void doSomething()
   {
      doSomething();
   }
```

In my case, the assertion fails because JMH calls the @Setup method again after the first benchmark method (before starting the second benchmark method). I’m completely confused. Do you have any idea what’s going on?

Thanks in fortune

Comment: It does exactly what the documentation states. Execute the method before the benchmark. You have multiple `@Benchmark` methods thus multiple invocations of the `@Setup`. Also you are incrementing a static field, which is class level not instance level.

Comment: So there is no equivalent of BeforeAll?

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be a `static` initializer block.

Comment: JMH, not like some test frameworks like JUnit, will execute the methods many times to let the JVM to a hot running state(JIT involves) and measure the performance of the code, not used for testing purposes such as asserting some logic is right or not. In that case, please use the Unit test framework instead.  See https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-performance/jmh.html for more info.